# I can't find out why my ticks are grey on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I have some ::after elements which appear when something has been selected in gravity forms on my image choices, on my normal browser (chrome) they appear as they should a green circle with a white tick, but on my mobile browser (chrome) they are a green circle with a grey tick.

I have looked and sifted through the code but i can't find out for the life of me whats making them grey!

the form can be found here: https://swallows.growthgun.com/book-performance-package

[screenshot of grey tick on my mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htHWI.jpg)
any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried using safaris inspect element to look at my phone screen directly and everything says the color should be #fff

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Could not be reproduced on mobile chrome with multiple devices and versions. Please use Code Snippets instead of links.

Comment: Working fine on my mobile Chrome. Can you provide a screenshot of that behaviour?

Comment: Hi guys really sorry definitely new to this, i will update it!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your theme's Custom CSS:

```
.elementor-icon svg:before {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

If that fails please provide an actual link to your site which works. The link you provided leads to an empty page.